# is there a way to fix this issue "Could not find android.multidex:multidex:2.0.1."

Tags: android-studio

hello im having yet another issue with my program i had ran the app and it had come up with this "Could not find android.multidex:multidex:2.0.1." I had typed in "implementation androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
the error is still  occurring  please help

Comment: you probably haven't add `google()` repositories in your project `build.gradle`.

Comment: repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Comment: still the error

Comment: Have you correctly add `implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"` to your `app` build.gradle `dependencies`? If you've correctly add it, make sure your gradle set to connect to internet.

Comment: implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'

    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.2'
    
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'

Comment: Use `2.0.1` because there is no `2.0.2` version:
`implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"`

Comment: ok that seems to be  sorted thank you! but my app keeps stopping on the simulator

Comment: Great, your next problem is because you haven't properly set the multidex. See https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#mdex-gradle.

Comment: And, please create your own answer to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

in build.gradle(:app)

```
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xyz"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

try writing  multiDexEnabled true

Comment: i think i may have to re start the whole thing still an error then more errors occurred

Comment: implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'    and multiDexEnabled true will work I guess

Comment: ok ive done that now it shows an error in my fragments folder

Comment: .Fragments.CreateAccountFragments">

Comment: can you send photos on here ?

Comment: tools:context=".Fragments".Fragments.CreateAccountFragments">

Comment: and my main activity    tools:context=".MainActivity"> this is an error also when it wasn't before

Comment: and my login fragment has come up in a error too     tools:context=".Fragments".Fragments.CreateAccountFragments">